# How to add a Product Catalogue Field

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms

I have a drupal commerce website, where i have items separateed by category: see [here](https://pasteboard.co/bB4Q4fRQ1.png)

I'd like to add as well, another field called BRAND, so that an item can be associated to both a category ie: CHIPS and a brand: ie Lays

i've tried to create another taxonomy term, but it doesn't appear then when i create the product.

I'd like to have this inserted as well as a criteria in the search form.

how can i do this?

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.

Nevertheless, maybe you misunderstand **taxonomy vocabulary** and **taxonomy term**? I would have expected that you create **two** vocabularies: one for **brand** and another one for **category**. Both should be referenced by your content type for products.